# C++ object equality

Tags: c++, pointers, equality

I have a class `MyCloth` and one one object instance of that class that I instantiated like this:

```
MyCloth** cloth1;
```

And at one point in the program, I will do something like this:

```
MyCloth** cloth2 = cloth1;
```

And then at some point later, I want to check to see if `cloth1` and `cloth2` are the same. (Something like object equality in Java, only here, `MyCloth` is a very complex class and I can''t build an `isEqual` function.)

How can I do this equality check? I was thinking maybe checking if they point to the same addresses. Is that a good idea? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: You do *not* have an "object of class `MyCloth`". If you believe that, you *really* have to rethink a lot about C++.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I was just trying to explain what I want to do, I know I can''t have an object of class MyCloth, but I didn''t know how else to put it, I''m new to C++ and trying to figure it out as I create a project.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: cloth1 and cloth2 are pointers of pointers (each cloth consists of pointers which define its parameters, behaviour, and so on)

Comment: What you wanna do is verify if each pointers point to the same memory allocation ?

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp: Yes, I hope that would work. How do I do that? like this: If(&cloth1 == &cloth2) ?

Comment: @user2399378 I know they ARE ptr ptrs, I just have no idea why you are using them.

Comment: @ MadScienceDreams: as I said before, I''m new to C++ and I don''t really get along with pointers very well. I don''t know how to handle pointers, I am using an auxiliary program which offered an example, and in that example, they wrote the code just like I wrote it here

Comment: @user2399378 Pointers are just a location in memory space. It is an address to a location in memory. The "type" of the pointer denotes how to interpret the ones and zeros in that location. When you use a pointer pointer, you have an address of an address. None of what you have points to an instance of a class. However, if you did initialize a class, like 'MyCloth* c1 = new MyCloth();' Than you can use 'MyCloth* c2 = NULL;/*or whatever*/ c1==c2;' to check if it is the same instance by determining whether or not the two pointers are to the same memory.This does NOT work with virtual inheritance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can test for object *identity* by comparing the addresses held by two pointers. You mention Java; this is similar to testing that two references are equal.

```
MyCloth* pcloth1 = ...
MyCloth* pcloth2 = ...
if ( pcloth1 == pcloth2 ) {
    // Then both point at the same object.
}
```

You can test for object *equality* by comparing the contents of two objects. In C++, this is usually done by defining `operator==`.

```
class MyCloth {
   friend bool operator== (MyCloth & lhs, MyCloth & rhs );
   ...
};

bool operator== ( MyCloth & lhs, MyCloth & rhs )
{
   return ...
}
```

With operator== defined, you can compare equality:

```
MyCloth cloth1 = ...
MyCloth cloth2 = ...
if ( cloth1 == cloth2 ) {
    // Then the two objects are considered to have equal values.
}
```

Comment: Given MyCloth *pcloth1, *pcloth2; how would one compare the contents of the two? your example shows how to do it for non-pointers only.

Comment: @user2813274 -- `if ( *pcloth1 == *pcloth2 ) ...`

Comment: How can you tell if that is checking where the pointers point to, or if the contents of the two locations are the same?

Comment: @user2813274 - The value of your `pcloth1` is an address. The value of `*pcloth1` is a MyCloth object. The expression `*pcloth1` *dereferences* the pointer pcloth1. Since both operands in the expression are MyCloth objects, the contents are checked, rather than the addresses.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to define a method by which to order a comparison of a set of objects of your custom class.  For example:

```
someClass instance1;
someClass instance2;
```

You can do so by overloading the < operator for this class.

```
class someClass
{
    
    bool operator<(someClass& other) const
    {
        //implement your ordering logic here
    }
};
```

If what you want to do is compare, and see if the objects are literally the same object, you can do a simple pointer comparison to see if they point to the same object.  I think your question is poorly worded, I'm not sure which you're going for.

EDIT:

For the second method, it's really quite easy.  You need access to the memory location of your object.  You can access this in many different ways.  Here are a few:

```
class someClass
{
    
    bool operator==(someClass& other) const
    {
        if(this == &other) return true; //This is the pointer for 
        else return false;
    }
};
```

Note: I do not like the above, as usually == operators go more in-depth than just comparing pointers.  Objects can represent objects of similar qualities without being the same, but this is an option.  YOu can also do this.

```
someClass *instancePointer = new someClass();
someClass instanceVariable;
someClass *instanceVariablePointer = &instanceVariable;


instancePointer == instanceVariable;
```

This is non-sensical and invalid/false.  If it would even compile, depending on your flags, hopefully you're using flags that wouldn't allow this!

```
instancePointer == &instanceVariable;
```

This is valid and would result in false.

```
instancePointer == instanceVaribalePointer;
```

This is also valid and would result in false.

```
instanceVariablePointer == &instanceVariable;
```

This is also valid and would result in TRUE.

```
instanceVariable == *instanceVariablePointer;
```

This would use the == operator we defined above to get the result of TRUE;

Comment: The OP is trying to test object identity or equality, not compare. Also, the OP specifies "MyCloth is a very complex class and I can''t build an isEqual function".

Comment: The second variant that you describe. How do I do that?

Comment: @user2399378 Using `==` to compare pointers will check that they point at the exact same memory location.