# How do i output properties of a pointer object in c++ (with 2 or more properties)

Tags: c++

```
Class A
{ 
  public:
    A();
    A(int x , int y);
  Private:
    int x;
    int y;
}

Class B
{
   public:
   B();
   A getApointerobject() const;

   Private:
   A *APointerObject;

int main()
{ 
  B bObj;
    cout << bObj.getApointerobject(); //i overloaded the << so that i can //output B objects but it crushes  

}

//Class B implementation (This is where i struggle)

  A getApointerobject() const { 

   return *getApointerobject;
}
```

Comment: I guess `getApointerobject` returns `this->APointerObject` ?

Comment: Please describe more clearly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In B::getApointerobject() you call it recursively. You should change to

```
A getApointerobject() const { 
    return *APointerObject;
}
```

Is B::APointerObject initialized before you call getApointerobject() method?

Comment: There's no recursive call, just uncompilable code in the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

In `getApointerobject` you are trying to return the address of the method `getApointerobject` itself. I guess you code is not even compiling right now?

I guess you want to return your `APointerObject`

```
  A B::getApointerobject() const { 

   return *this->APointerObject;
}
```

**But be advised**: Built in types, including simple pointers don't have a default constructor. So, since you don't initialise `APointerObject` in `class B`s constructor, you would use a wild pointer. Which means you program would **crash at runtime or worse** (undefined behavior)

Comment: I have done return *APointerObject, how do i output the returned value in int  main() to test if its pointing to what i intend to get to point to

Comment: Do you want to test for the identity or equality? For the difference see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16843956/3537677